# How can I make this Route (ASP.Net MVC2)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I'm begginer in asp.net mvc and I have some doutbs about routes.

Im' developing a system to manage documents and I need make an URL like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Documentos",
            "{controller}/{documentType}/{documento}/{action}/{id}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                documentType = "",
                documento = "",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

and the app working an URL like theses:

"Document/Administrative/Contract" - (Index action by default to list documents of type 'Contract')
"Document/Administrative/Contract/New" - (new action in controller)
"Document/Administrative/Contract/10" - (detail action in controller)
"Document/Administrative/Contract/Edit/10" - (edit action in controller)

Document would be a Controller, and Administrative would be just a description in url to identify that documents of 'Contract' is Administrative...

So, My doubts is about my controllers and actions, How should be the signature of the methods of controller ? Need I make an Area called Documents to do this more easy ?

PS: Sorry for my english!

Thanks a lot,
Cheers!

Felipe

Answer (score 0):

Just have 1 controller Document.

In this controller have actions Index
, New  and Edit.

All actions need to have parameters documentType and  documento or (better) you have a 
Viewmodel as a parameter that has properties documentType and documento.

Pass this Viewmodel to the view. In the view use Html.ActionLink to generate Links that have documentType and documento set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes.MapRoute("Documentos", 
            "Document/{documentType}/{documento}/{action}/{id}", 
            new 
            { 
                controller = "Document", 
                documentType = "", 
                documento = "", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            });
```

When you want an URL of "Document/Administrative/Contract" to default to the List you have to make a hardcoded route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Documentos", 
            "Document/Administrative/Contract", 
            new 
            { 
                controller = "Document", 
                documentType = "Administrative", 
                documento = "Contract", 
                action = "List"
            });
```

Your actions should plainly contain the same names for the parameters as you use in routes. Or combine the parameters in Model classes.

```
public ActionResult(string documentType, string documento, int id)
```

or

```
public ActionResult(Document doc)
```

if you use Model class Document.

```
public class Document
string documentType;
string documento;
int id;
```

HTH